# Setting print ticket description when writing with XpsDocumentWriter

Tags: wpf, printing

If I print to a PDF driver (Bullzip) using PrintVisual as in

```
pd.PrintVisual(myPage, "Document name");
```

then the Bullzip driver gives a default filename of "Document Name.pdf" which is ideal. But I'm actually wanting to use an XpsDocumentWriter rather than printing a single visual.

Is there any way of setting the Document description - I can't see anything that might do it in PrintDialog, PrintTicket or PrintQueue.

Tx

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's:

```
pd.PrintQueue.CurrentJobSettings.Description = "Document Name";
```

Comment: make sure to mark your Answer as "Answer" if it is the Answer to your Question and +1 for saving my time with your solution ;)